# How to Read/Write Contacts and Events in Outlook when it is set to Work Offline - C#

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-interop, com-interop

As the Title suggest, i am trying to Read and Write (R&W) Contact and Event information to multiple **Outlook** Accounts/Profiles in a local computer, while **Outlook** is set to Work Offline.

So far i discovered two ways to R&W contacts and Events to **Outlook**:

**1.- **Microsoft.Graph**:**

This seems to work only online, since it reads and writes to the **Microsoft server**, not to the local pst/ost files.

**2.- microsoft.office.interop.outlook library:**

This does work offline/locally (by accessing the **Outlook** pst/ost files) but the approach i am using so far requires the creation of an `Application` object as

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

Nevertheless, creating an **Application** object implicitly logs in a profile/user to the application, and further, if **Outlook** is already running and logged in with a Profile X, the code above instantiates an **Outlook** object in which the Profile X is logged in, so in that scenario i can only R&W Contacts and Events for that specific user/Profile.

So, is there a way to be able to R&W Contact and Event information for different profiles independently of if **Outlook** is running with a Profile X?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no magic - if you want offline access, something needs to implement the storage to keep the cached data and cache your changes so that they can be uploaded when the server comes back online.

If you don't want to implement that logic, cached Outlook profile is probably your only choice. You are right that Outlook, being a singleton, can only access one profile at a time. You can use Extended MAPI to access a profile other than the other used by Outlook, but it is C++ or Delphi only. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it wraps Extended MAPI API for use in any language (C# included) - you can use its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Logon` method to access any existing profile.

Comment: You are right, i am looking for a Cached Outlook solution: i want to read/write to the pst/ost files. Do you know about any .Net based library/solution to access the Outlook pst/ost files?

Comment: I don't think there is one. What you need is Extended MAPI, either directly in C++ or Delphi or a MAPI wrapper (such as Redemption).